# Why is Boost VF2 subgraph isomorphism giving an incorrect answer?

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

I'm trying to use Boost's `vf2_subgraph_iso`, and I'm getting the wrong answer when testing subgraph isomorphism between a pair of small graphs. The code is as follows :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/labeled_graph.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/vf2_sub_graph_iso.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/property_map.hpp>

using namespace boost;


typedef property<edge_name_t, char> edge_prop;
typedef property<vertex_name_t, char, property<vertex_index_t, int> > vertex_prop;

typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, bidirectionalS, vertex_prop, edge_prop> Graph;

typedef property_map<Graph, vertex_name_t>::type vertex_name_map_t;
typedef property_map_equivalent<vertex_name_map_t, vertex_name_map_t> vertex_comp_t;

typedef property_map<Graph, edge_name_t>::type edge_name_map_t;
typedef property_map_equivalent<edge_name_map_t, edge_name_map_t> edge_comp_t;

bool is_subgraph_isomorphic(Graph smallGraph, Graph bigGraph)
{
    vertex_comp_t vertex_comp =
        make_property_map_equivalent(get(vertex_name, smallGraph), get(vertex_name, bigGraph));
    edge_comp_t edge_comp =
        make_property_map_equivalent(get(edge_name, smallGraph), get(edge_name, bigGraph));
    vf2_print_callback<Graph, Graph> callback(smallGraph, bigGraph);
    bool res = vf2_subgraph_iso(smallGraph, bigGraph, callback, vertex_order_by_mult(smallGraph),
        edges_equivalent(edge_comp).vertices_equivalent(vertex_comp));
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    Graph gsmall,glarge;
    add_vertex(vertex_prop('a'),gsmall);
    add_vertex(vertex_prop('b'),gsmall);
    add_edge(0, 1, edge_prop('a'), gsmall);
    add_vertex(vertex_prop('a'),glarge);
    add_vertex(vertex_prop('b'),glarge);
    add_vertex(vertex_prop('a'),glarge);
    add_edge(0, 1, edge_prop('b'), glarge);
    add_edge(1, 2, edge_prop('a'), glarge);
    std::cout << "Is first pair subisomorphic ? : " << is_subgraph_isomorphic(gsmall,glarge) << std::endl;

    Graph graph1;

    add_vertex(vertex_prop('a'), graph1);
    add_vertex(vertex_prop('a'), graph1);
    add_vertex(vertex_prop('a'), graph1);

    add_edge(0, 1, edge_prop('b'), graph1); 
    add_edge(0, 1, edge_prop('b'), graph1); 
    add_edge(0, 1, edge_prop('d'), graph1); 

    add_edge(1, 2, edge_prop('s'), graph1); 

    add_edge(2, 2, edge_prop('l'), graph1); 
    add_edge(2, 2, edge_prop('l'), graph1); 

    // Build graph2
    Graph graph2;

    add_vertex(vertex_prop('a'), graph2);
    add_vertex(vertex_prop('a'), graph2);
    add_vertex(vertex_prop('a'), graph2);
    add_vertex(vertex_prop('a'), graph2);
    add_vertex(vertex_prop('a'), graph2);
    add_vertex(vertex_prop('a'), graph2);

    add_edge(0, 1, edge_prop('a'), graph2); 
    add_edge(0, 1, edge_prop('a'), graph2); 
    add_edge(0, 1, edge_prop('b'), graph2); 

    add_edge(1, 2, edge_prop('s'), graph2); 

    add_edge(2, 3, edge_prop('b'), graph2); 
    add_edge(2, 3, edge_prop('d'), graph2); 
    add_edge(2, 3, edge_prop('b'), graph2); 

    add_edge(3, 4, edge_prop('s'), graph2); 

    add_edge(4, 4, edge_prop('l'), graph2); 
    add_edge(4, 4, edge_prop('l'), graph2); 

    add_edge(4, 5, edge_prop('c'), graph2); 
    add_edge(4, 5, edge_prop('c'), graph2); 
    add_edge(4, 5, edge_prop('c'), graph2); 

    add_edge(5, 0, edge_prop('s'), graph2); 
    std::cout << "Is second pair subisomorphic ? : " << is_subgraph_isomorphic(graph1,graph2) << std::endl;
}
```

The first is a pair of simple graphs, and the second is the graph from the [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/graph/example/vf2_sub_graph_iso_multi_example.cpp) given in the Boost docs.

The code seems to give the right answer for the Boost example but gives the wrong answer for the first. Here is the output :

```
Is first pair subisomorphic ? : 0
(0, 2) (1, 3) (2, 4) 
Is second pair subisomorphic ? : 1
```

The first pair obviously is subgraph isomorphic.

Another curious thing I noticed was that when I changed

```
typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, bidirectionalS, vertex_prop, edge_prop> Graph;
```

to

```
typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, undirectedS, vertex_prop, edge_prop> Graph;
```

the output is now

```
(0, 2) (1, 1) 
Is first pair subisomorphic ? : 1
Is second pair subisomorphic ? : 0
```

Which is correct for the first pair but wrong for the second.

Compilation command :

```
g++ "-std=c++11" code.cpp -lboost_graph -o exec
```

Running on Xubuntu 16.04, up to date as far as I can tell. Using the Boost library from the repositories.

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you know what `bidirectionalS` means? It means, among other things, that `edge(1,2,g)` is not equivalent to `edge(2,1,g)`.

Comment: I am new to boost, and it seems I've misunderstood that. However, that means I should have gotten both pairs sub-isomorphic when I used `undirectedS`, correct ? Because the second pair is sub-isomorphic when I used `bidirectionalS`, when the edges have direction, so the same mapping should work in the undirected case.

Comment: I can't understand why that second example fails when using `undirectedS` either.

Comment: It's the exact same example given in the boost docs, so I don't know how that could happen. I suppose the only thing I can do now is to see if this happens on a different version on a different distro.

Answer (score 0):

I think you discovered a bug or actually two. Your example shows that `vf2_subgraph_iso` can't handle self-loops when using `undirectedS`. If you remove them, your example should work.
The second one is an inconsistency. In the documentation it's said that `vf2_subgraph_iso` returns true if a graph-subgraph isomorphism exists and false otherwise. But actually it returns true if the entire search space was explored and false otherwise.
Best regards,

Comment: It does seem it can't handle self loops and even multiple edges between the same vertices. I'll do some testing some time later for this. Just to clarify, by "inconsistency" you mean that the search here terminates prematurely due to being unable to handle self loops and/or multiple edges, and so such termination is not equivalent to non-existence of a graph-subgraph isomorphism ?

Comment: I'm sorry. There is no Inconsistency regarding the return value. I accidentally looked at an old version of the code.