# Boost VF2 subgraph isomorphism incorrect for undirected graphs?

Tags: c++, boost-graph

I'm trying to use Boost's `vf2_subgraph_iso` but I can't figure out how to use it properly for small undirected graphs.

Below I show an example where a graph with 4 vertices is not a sub-graph of the fully connected graph with 4 vertices (which seems odd to me). Could anyone help me to understand what I'm doing wrong here?

I've seen the post at [Why is Boost VF2 subgraph isomorphism giving an incorrect answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354933/why-is-boost-vf2-subgraph-isomorphism-giving-an-incorrect-answer), which could be the same problem.

```
#include <boost/graph/vf2_sub_graph_iso.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/graph/vf2_sub_graph_iso.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost;

int main()
{
    typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, undirectedS, no_property> Graph;

    // 0---1
    // |   |
    // 2---3

    Graph smallGraph;
    {
        vertex(0, smallGraph);
        vertex(1, smallGraph);
        vertex(2, smallGraph);
        vertex(3, smallGraph);

        add_edge(0, 1, smallGraph);
        add_edge(0, 2, smallGraph);
        add_edge(2, 3, smallGraph);
        add_edge(1, 3, smallGraph);
    }

    Graph largeGraph;
    {
        vertex(0, largeGraph);
        vertex(1, largeGraph);
        vertex(2, largeGraph);
        vertex(3, largeGraph);

        add_edge(0, 1, largeGraph);
        add_edge(0, 2, largeGraph);
        add_edge(2, 3, largeGraph);
        add_edge(1, 3, largeGraph);

        add_edge(0, 3, largeGraph);
        add_edge(1, 2, largeGraph);
    }

    vf2_print_callback<Graph, Graph> callback(smallGraph, largeGraph);
    auto val = vf2_subgraph_iso(smallGraph, largeGraph, callback);

    if (val)
        std::cout << "Found subgraph." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Did not find subgraph." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

From [vf2_subgraph_iso documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/graph/doc/vf2_sub_graph_iso.html#boost-common-heading-doc-spacer:%7E:text=An%20isomorphism%20between%20two%20graphs), "An isomorphism between two graphs G1=(V1, E1) and G2=(V2, E2) is a bijective mapping M of the vertices of one graph to vertices of the other graph that preserves the edge structure of the graphs. M is said to be a graph-subgraph isomorphism if and only if M is an isomorphism between G1 and a subgraph of G2."

In my example above, G2 = largeGraph, G1 = smallGraph, and there exists a subgraph of G2 such that the vertex mapping (0-0, 1-1, 2-2, 3-3) is bijective between the subgraph and G1.

Answer (score 0):

Subgraph isomorphism [is defined here as](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/graph/doc/vf2_sub_graph_iso.html#boost-common-heading-doc-spacer:%7E:text=An%20isomorphism%20between%20two%20graphs):

> An isomorphism between two graphs G1=(V1, E1) and G2=(V2, E2) is a bijective mapping M of the vertices of one graph to vertices of the other graph that preserves the edge structure of the graphs

What mapping did you expect to hold? I'm thinking you might have been expecting {0 -> 0, 1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3} to be that *bijective vertex mapping*?

However, that's not the case because the subgraph is then missing edges between vertices participating in the mapping. E.g. `3 -- 0` is not in the small graph, making it structurally different.

> **TL;DR** A subgraph isomorphism is **not** when edges are a strict subset. Instead, it focuses on mapping sets of vertices.

### Counter Example

Here's counter example which generates some random edges while preserving the intended mappings. Note how given enough random edges you will likely run into accidental iso-morphisms because the sub-graph is structurally that simple:

**[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hyGYsj52acH2G0H0)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/vf2_sub_graph_iso.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#include <random>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/cxx11/all_of.hpp>

using boost::make_iterator_range;
using boost::adaptors::transformed;
using boost::algorithm::all_of;

int main()
{
    using Graph =
        boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS>;
    using V = Graph::vertex_descriptor;

    // 0---1
    // |   |
    // 2---3
    Graph small(4);
    add_edge(0, 1, small);
    add_edge(0, 2, small);
    add_edge(2, 3, small);
    add_edge(1, 3, small);

    Graph large(500);
    add_edge(100, 200, large);
    add_edge(100, 300, large);
    add_edge(300, 400, large);
    add_edge(200, 400, large);

    // helper to recognizes (sets of) vertices from the intended subset
    auto all_in_subset = [set = std::set{100, 200, 300, 400}](auto... vs) {
        return ((0 != set.count(vs)) && ...);
    };

    // add some random edges for
    auto randvertex = std::bind(
        std::uniform_int_distribution<V>(0, boost::num_vertices(large) - 1),
        std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});

    for (int n = 0; n < 400; ++n) {
        V src = randvertex();
        V tgt = randvertex();

        // only add edges outside of the subset - preserving structure
        if (!all_in_subset(src, tgt))
            add_edge(src, tgt, large);
    }

    auto callback = [&](auto bijection, auto) {
        auto vs = make_iterator_range(vertices(small));
        auto mapped =
            vs | transformed([&](auto v) { return get(bijection, v); });

        if (boost::algorithm::all_of(mapped, all_in_subset)) {
            std::cout << "In subset: ";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Random match: ";
        }

        for (auto v : vs) {
            std::cout << '(' << v << " -> " << get(bijection, v) << ") ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        return true;
    };
    bool found = boost::vf2_subgraph_iso(small, large, callback);

    std::cout << "Found subgraph:" << std::boolalpha << found << std::endl;
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
In subset: (0 -> 100) (1 -> 200) (2 -> 300) (3 -> 400) 
In subset: (0 -> 100) (1 -> 300) (2 -> 200) (3 -> 400) 
Random match: (0 -> 122) (1 -> 268) (2 -> 454) (3 -> 128) 
Random match: (0 -> 122) (1 -> 454) (2 -> 268) (3 -> 128) 
Random match: (0 -> 128) (1 -> 268) (2 -> 454) (3 -> 122) 
Random match: (0 -> 128) (1 -> 454) (2 -> 268) (3 -> 122) 
In subset: (0 -> 200) (1 -> 100) (2 -> 400) (3 -> 300) 
In subset: (0 -> 200) (1 -> 400) (2 -> 100) (3 -> 300) 
Random match: (0 -> 220) (1 -> 234) (2 -> 367) (3 -> 340) 
Random match: (0 -> 220) (1 -> 367) (2 -> 234) (3 -> 340) 
Random match: (0 -> 234) (1 -> 220) (2 -> 340) (3 -> 367) 
Random match: (0 -> 234) (1 -> 340) (2 -> 220) (3 -> 367) 
Random match: (0 -> 268) (1 -> 122) (2 -> 128) (3 -> 454) 
Random match: (0 -> 268) (1 -> 128) (2 -> 122) (3 -> 454) 
In subset: (0 -> 300) (1 -> 100) (2 -> 400) (3 -> 200) 
In subset: (0 -> 300) (1 -> 400) (2 -> 100) (3 -> 200) 
Random match: (0 -> 340) (1 -> 234) (2 -> 367) (3 -> 220) 
Random match: (0 -> 340) (1 -> 367) (2 -> 234) (3 -> 220) 
Random match: (0 -> 367) (1 -> 220) (2 -> 340) (3 -> 234) 
Random match: (0 -> 367) (1 -> 340) (2 -> 220) (3 -> 234) 
In subset: (0 -> 400) (1 -> 200) (2 -> 300) (3 -> 100) 
In subset: (0 -> 400) (1 -> 300) (2 -> 200) (3 -> 100) 
Random match: (0 -> 454) (1 -> 122) (2 -> 128) (3 -> 268) 
Random match: (0 -> 454) (1 -> 128) (2 -> 122) (3 -> 268) 
Found subgraph:true
```

Or, depending on luck, just the expected: **[Live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Uf0jwAUmHcpAFsPk)**

```
In subset: (0 -> 100) (1 -> 200) (2 -> 300) (3 -> 400) 
In subset: (0 -> 100) (1 -> 300) (2 -> 200) (3 -> 400) 
In subset: (0 -> 200) (1 -> 100) (2 -> 400) (3 -> 300) 
In subset: (0 -> 200) (1 -> 400) (2 -> 100) (3 -> 300) 
In subset: (0 -> 300) (1 -> 100) (2 -> 400) (3 -> 200) 
In subset: (0 -> 300) (1 -> 400) (2 -> 100) (3 -> 200) 
In subset: (0 -> 400) (1 -> 200) (2 -> 300) (3 -> 100) 
In subset: (0 -> 400) (1 -> 300) (2 -> 200) (3 -> 100) 
Found subgraph:true
```

Comment: Simplified and re-complicated the sample in a working demo that illustrates how iso-morphisms are mapped

Comment: Hi sehe, thanks for the answer! You're correct I was expecting the 0-0, 1-1, 2-2, 3-3 mapping. 

It does seem like I was misunderstanding what a subgraph isomorphism was -- I was interpreting it to be when the small graph is isomorphic to any subgraph of the large graph. Does this property have a name?

And the difference between that and the definition you gave is that the edge structure of the mapped vertices must be the same between the isomorphic graphs, is that correct?

Comment: I don't actually think that difference exists. I think the "small graph is isomorphic to a subgraph of the large graph" **implies** the edge structure must match. So, there will not be a separate name for it. I also fear that any "less strict" match will be rather meaningless.

Comment: In a sense it's sad that it doesn't "get the obvious edge subsets". However, in many senses the isomorphism mapping is superior [as the matches in randomly generated edges hopefully illustrated]. In effect the tool is better at detecting patterns in unknown data, than at recovering known subsets from data. Now I wonder how difficult it would be to make a 'edge-set-oriented matching algorithm' (I'm no mathematician/topologist, as you can probably tell).

Comment: I'm not completely sure about that, if you consider the vertex set to be the same in my example (i.e. vertex 1 from small graph = vertex 1 from large graph) then I feel that the small graph is a subgraph of the large graph because the vertex sets are identical and the small graph's edge set is a subset of the large graph's edge set. This is the sense that I'd expect the small graph to be subgraph isomorphic to the large graph. -- perhaps I should be looking for a simple sub-graph algorithm.

Comment: Subgraph is not the same as isomorphism. Perhaps you're just looking for the word that's right in front of you: _subgraph_? I wonder whether such algorithms exist. Also, I wonder whether you have the "vertex id matching" condition as a given, because that makes the algorithm trivial.

Comment: I'm not so sure, just taking a quick look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem makes me feel like I'm interpreting the problem correctly. "...one must determine whether G contains a subgraph that is isomorphic to H" is the problem I'm trying to solve for the case where G is the large graph and H is the small graph.

Comment: @Clayton The detail you are looking for might be the difference between a induced subgraph isomorphism and a non-induced subgraph isomorphism. It seems like the implementations are all using induced subgraph isomorphism. In a non-induced subgraph isomorphism it is not required that the subgraph has all the edges of the target-graph (connecting the nodes that are part of it). Unfortunately it seems to me that there is no efficient implementation for the non-induced subgraph isomorphism. There are many improvements for the induced case.